# Access nested struct with offset

Tags: c, memcpy

I wanted to use structure offsets to access nested elements of a struct, but the following test program doesn't copy over the string correctly. How can I fix this snippet(it crashes). It seems like it does not jump over to the nested struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char a;
    int  b;
    char c[10];
    char d[10];
}foo_t;

typedef struct {
    foo_t foo;
}super_foo_t;

super_foo_t test;

int main() {
    memcpy(&(test.foo) + offsetof(foo_t, c), "hello", sizeof("hello"));
    printf("c should be hello:%s\n", test.foo.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider the type of `&test.foo` and how pointer arithmetic works. (Or just print the various pointers involved with `printf`+`%p`.) Also, when is this better than `&test.foo.c`?

Comment: oo yeah you are right. it will offset the size of foo_t those many times. I am trying to shorten my code which does a string compare for a list of strings and copies contents into the struct. If I know the offset, I can store it in an array and iterate over to shorten my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are offsetting "foo_t" pointer so it will be equivalent of &test.foo[offsetof(foo_t, c)] because "&test.foo" is type of "foo_t*"...

You need to tell compiler that the offset is in bytes specifically like below:

```
memcpy((char*)(&(test.foo)) + offsetof(foo_t, c), "hello", sizeof("hello"));
```

Because offset of gives you offset in bytes and you need to calculate using bytes offset. So if you needed to access member "b" you should have written like below:

```
int * ptrB = (int*) ((char*)(&(test.foo)) + offsetof(foo_t, b));
*ptrB = 15;
```

What we are doing below is this we are first converting the pointer to bytes so the compiler will calculate offset as bytes then we can return back to the original pointer-type.

Comment: oh yes, dammit. Thanks